# Length of maximal ideal in noetherian ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian

Let $A$ be a noetherian commutative ring and $\mathfrak{m}$ a maximal ideal. Is it possible to have $ht(\mathfrak{m}) > 1$? Here $ht(\mathfrak{m})$ is the height of $\mathfrak{m}$, that is the supremum of length of chains of prime ideals contained in $\mathfrak{m}$.

I think no but I'm unable to prove it. But my intuition is only derived from examples on finitely generated rings over a field...

---

EDIT : In fact I was looking for this question : is it possible to have $dim(A/\mathfrak{m}) > 1$? Sorry for the misunderstood... In fact my question comes from a scheme context (I'd like to show that a locally closed point x in a locally noetherian scheme X verify $\bar{\{x\}}$ is of dimension $\leq 1$).  I translated it in a commutative algebra fact but I make a mistake in the first formulation.

Comment: About the edit: Dimension over which field? Also maybe it is better to ask a separate question since your original question has been answered. This brings extra visibility to the new one and also does not, generally speaking, "invalidate" the answers given to the original one, like it seems now.

Comment: Hi, you are right... It is the Krull dimension here.

Comment: $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field, and a field has Krull dimension $0$. But I assume you already know that.

Comment: Hi indeed it's obvious... I get myself confused... I create a new conversation... I'm sorry

Comment: I start a new discussion here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833829/locally-closed-point-in-locally-noetherian-scheme . I should to do this at first. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider in $k[x_1,x_2]$ the chain of prime ideals $(0)\subseteq(x_1)\subseteq(x_2,x_2)=:\mathfrak m$.

Comment: In fact, any 2-dimensional (or higher) commutative ring will give a counterexample.

Comment: You are right thanks but...

Comment: I realised I maked a mistake (cf. the edit...). Sorry.