# Locally closed point in locally noetherian scheme

Tags: commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $X$ be a locally noetherian scheme. Let $x \in X$ be such that $\{x\}$ is locally closed (*i.e.* is of the form $U \cap F$ where $U$ is open and $F$ closed). I want to show
$\bar{ \{x\} }$ has its topological dimension $\leq 1$.

I tried to simplified the problem into a commutative algebra statement here [Length of maximal ideal in noetherian ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833117/length-of-maximal-ideal-in-noetherian-ring?noredirect=1#comment10290393_4833117)  but I get my self confused and I released it wasn't enough.

Do you have ideas?

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Many thanks!